# XElement.Load Error reading ampersand symbols and special country characters

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having problems reading the ampersand symbol from an XML file:

```
XElement xmlElements = XElement.Load(Path_Xml_Data_File);
```

I get error when I have:

```
<Name>Patrick & Phill</Name>

Error: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Xml.XmlException) A System.Xml.XmlException was thrown: "Name cannot begin with the ' ' character
```

Or with special Portuguese characters:

```
<Extra>Direc&ccedil;&atilde;o Assistida</Extra> (= <Extra>Direcção Assistida</Extra>)

Error: Reference to undeclared entity 'ccedil'
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you're dealing with malformed XML.

To represent the ampersand, the data that you're loading should use the "&amp;" entity.

The &ccedil; (ç) and &atilde; (ã) named entities are not part of the XML standard, they are more commonly found in HTML (although they can be added to XML by the use of a DTD).

You could use HtmlTidy to tidy up the data first, or you could write something to convert the bare ampersands into entities on the incoming files.

For example:

```
public string CleanUpData(string data)
{
    var r = new Regex(@"&\s");
    string output = r.Replace(data, "&amp; ");
    output = output.Replace("&ccedil;", "ç");
    output = output.Replace("&atilde;", "ã");
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but how can I do this before I XElement.Load the xml?

Comment: XElement.Parse(CleanUpData(File.ReadAllText(Path_Xml_Data_File)));